# Python: Questions about subprocess, piped data, and multiprocessing

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, multiprocessing, popen

I have a Python program that uses Popen to call a test C++ program.  The test C++ program simply writes 0-99999 to stdout.  The Python program has two functions that should be run as seperate processes.  One function, funcA, should launch the C++ program, read the integers from the stdout pipe, and insert those integers into a shared Queue.  The other function, funcB, should read and print the integers in the Queue until the Queue is empty.  I have some issues / questions that I will post below, along with my code below that.

1. What is the proper way for funcA to read from the C++ program's stdout until it (the C++ program) terminates?
2. What is the proper way for funcB to read from the shared Queue until all ints have been processed?

My current method for question 1 works, I believe, but I know there may be some issues that I don't check such as the Queue filling up.  Also, all the numbers are not printed out (stops at about 98000) and I think this might have something to do with funcA terminating and disrupting the shared Queue?  I am not exactly sure what to do for question 2 because the documentation says that one can't rely on empty() in a concurrent processing atmosphere and I don't want to use a while(1).

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import Queue

def funcA(intQueue):
    # call C++ program
    handle = subprocess.Popen(['../C++/C++.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while(handle.returncode == None):
        handle.stdout.readline()
        intQueue.put(handle.stdout.readline())
        handle.poll()

def funcB(intQueue):
    try:
        while(1):
            print intQueue.get(True, 2)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # shared Queue for all the processes
    intQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # producer - receives ints from the C++ stdout and inserts into Queue
    multiprocessing.Process(target=funcA, args=(intQueue,)).start()

    # consumer - prints ints from the Queue
    multiprocessing.Process(target=funcB, args=(intQueue,)).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this same problem:

For question 1 I used a while(1) that breaks when the list returned from a splitting of handle.stdout.read() has a length of 1 (this means that nothing was returned from the pipe).

For question 2 I used the poison pill method described in this post: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html

Comment: My question 1 solution would be problematic if the C++ program is producing output slower than the Python program is processing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method of `Popen`, like this:

```
handle = subprocess.Popen(['../C++/C++.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = handle.communicate()    # this will block until the underlying subprocess exits
```

As for the queue, the data structure defines methods to query said queue if it is full or empty. Utilize these.

Comment: The problem with using communicate is that, like you said, it will block until the underlying subprocess exits.  I definitely do not want this.  The actual C++ program that I will be running may take a large amount of time to deliver all of its output.  Also, the documentation states that full() and empty() can not be trusted when doing concurrent processing.  So, I would rather not use them as checks to determine whether procB should continue to run.

Comment: To address the first, you just need to spawn each `.communicate()` call in its own thread, or use a threadpool.

Comment: To address the second, they are not trusted *as is*. You can make them thread-safe yourself by using locks, event objects, etc, or any appropriate concurrent programming construct.

Comment: Are you sure the Queues and multiprocessing.Queues are not already setup for concurrency?  I thought that I read they were in the documentation.

Comment: When you call `.full()` or `.empty()`, it is thread-safe, in the sense that during the execution of those methods, no other threads would invariably change the "fullness" or the "emptiness" of the queue. Once you have your answer, though, the internal concurrency mechanism would have been released. In other words, between a check for `.empty()` and an insert operation that you falsely assumed to be safe, other threads might have inserted something to make the queue full.